# Use periods instead of frequencies in Comodulograms

Tags: bandpass, eeg

I want to create a Comodulogram to assess PAC. I use the pactools library, which uses frequencies. Since I work with hourly data and want to look at multidien phases, it would be better to use periods instead of frequencies.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pactools import Comodulogram, REFERENCES
from pactools import simulate_pac

fs = 24 # Hourly data, so 24/d
high_fq_range = np.linspace(1/3, 3, 30) # up to 6 days
low_fq_range = np.linspace( 1/(45),  1/(4.5), 50) # from 4.5d to 45d

low_fq_width = 1/100 

estimator = Comodulogram(fs=fs, high_fq_range=high_fq_range, low_fq_range=low_fq_range,
                            low_fq_width=low_fq_width, method='canolty',
                            progress_bar=False)
estimator.fit(df["Pattern A Channel 1"])
estimator.plot(titles=[REFERENCES[method]])
plt.show()
```

This code produces the reasonable plot:

[image: plot1]

To switch to periods, I used this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pactools import Comodulogram, REFERENCES
from pactools import simulate_pac

fs = 24 # Hourly data, so 24/d
high_fq_range = np.linspace(1/3, 3, 30) # up to 6 days
circadian_periods = np.flip(1/high_fq_range)
low_fq_range = np.linspace( 1/(45),  1/(4.5), 50) # from 4.5d to 45d
multidien_periods = np.flip(1/low_fq_range)

low_fq_width = 1/100 

estimator = Comodulogram(fs=fs, high_fq_range=high_fq_range, low_fq_range=low_fq_range,
                            low_fq_width=low_fq_width, method='canolty',
                            progress_bar=False)
estimator.fit(df["Pattern A Channel 1"])
comodulogram = estimator.comod_

extent = [
    multidien_periods[0],
    multidien_periods[-1],
    circadian_periods[0],
    circadian_periods[-1],
]
plt.imshow(comodulogram.T, aspect='auto', origin='lower', extent=extent,)
plt.xlabel('Multidien [days]')
plt.ylabel('Circadien [days]')
plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image: plot 2]

For me, this makes no sense, since the peak is at period 10, which does not correspond to a frequency at around 0.04 from the plot above. Is it possible to use this library with periods? And what would be the correct approach?

Thank you!